# How to write data to pdf file which contains html tags using itext lib in Java

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext

I have String which contains some html tags and it is coming from database, i want to write that in PDF file with same styling present in the String in the form of HTML tag. I tried to use XMLWorkerHelper like this

```
String html = What is the equation of the line passing through the 
point (2,-3) and making an angle of -45<sup>2</sup> with the positive 
X-axis?

XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, new 
StringReader(html));
```

but it only reads the data which is inside the html tag(in this case only 2) other string it simply ignores. But i want the entire String with HTML formating. 
With HTMLWorker it works perfectly but that is deprecated so please let me know how to achieve this.
I am using iText 5 lib

Comment: have you tried wrapping the string into a a <p> tag?

Comment: No i did not tried wrapping into <p> but i wrapped entire string into <html><body> and it worked also but it fails at certain point like when the string contains <(less than) or > (greater than),  then its gives error expecting <\body> tag

Comment: Escape your reserved characters? That should be pretty self explanatory when dealing with parsing components that use those characters

Comment: i have to read maths questions and in that > and < sings are being used heavily which is already present in DB i have to read that string and write the same in PDF

Comment: Replace them with their html or unicode equivalent? See https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%3C and https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%3E